# Pending Chain Balance -Lightning Wallet:

Tags: wallet, lightning-network, lightning-network-daemon, lightning-routing

I appear to have a stuck pending chain balance on my Lightning Node's Lightning Wallet.

It has remained a pending chain balance for a very long time can someone please let me know how I can get this pending chain balance to finalize and let me use the over 16 million sats that my Thunderhub App says I have in the walet.

Thank you for any help you can offer.

Orange_Bitcoin

Comment: Please define "very long time" a week is for example not long in this context and not uncommon

Comment: Hi Rene, I Believe it is approximately 4 weeks. Is there a way to check on its progress to locate the reason why it has yet to complete this process? Thank you.

Comment: Can you post the funding transaction or the short channel id?

Comment: I  will research what you have asked for and let you know soon. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry for my noobishness but here is a transaction from mempool for what I believe is the last channel we closed. https://mempool.space/tx/5ccb8159021030fd94d6b1ef1430cf7f1f3fd8a21884db05c781878d49431cdb

Comment: Sorry for my noobishness but here is a transaction from mempool for what I believe is the last channel we closed with bcashistrash. https://mempool.space/tx/5ccb8159021030fd94d6b1ef1430cf7f1f3fd8a21884db05c781878d49431cdb:1  closing transaction for bcash channel: https://mempool.space/tx/bbbebaf73af823fe1aec298ec6dbc4ccee98fedb77e33192c152ab2cf1b24e2d

Comment: 2nd part of the comment just above this one.   the 2nd newest channel we closed for the peer bfx-lnd0.  opening transaction: https://mempool.space/tx/8f2063f11886abf4aaeb091e3e95bb5aa53358f5f904376bdf75d5395a86b5f1:0  closing transaction: https://mempool.space/tx/ec5f625b2e357e8ebbfff57e0dbc5f04a3a4e32cdcb97356cb9ef16db7d76305   I hope I gave you the correct information you requested. Thank you so much!

Comment: Hi Rene, I am sorry to tell you this but the pending chain balance has finally resolved itself and is back in the wallet, hope we did not cause you any extra work than was necessary. Was the reason for it taking so long to finalize due to miners fees being higher than the closing fee we set it to at the time of the closing of our channels? We appreciate all of your help in our quest to be better node runners! Thank you :-)